# Aligning Bootstrap buttons on new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have two nav buttons in the top right of my nav bar "register" and "sign in", then have one separate button "request a demo" below it. I'm currently using a br tag to push the third one down but, on the new line it creates, it pushes the first two buttons left. Does anyone know a proper way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Please update your question to include your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Bootstrap, I'd put the Request Demo button on a new row. This will give you more control over each row of buttons (especially when shrinking to mobile).

```
<div class="row nav-row">
  <btn href="#">
    Register
  </btn>
  <btn href="#">
    Sign In
  </btn>
</div>

<div class="row nav-row">
  <btn class="demo" href="#">
      Request a demo
  </btn>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/marguerite/pen/JYdQPZ

This example does not use bootstrap's default button styles.

Answer (score 2):

**Recommendation**

I would break the "Request a Demo" into its own separate block / row. Don't lump it in with the "Sign In" and "Register."

**Rationale**

Based on your question, the content seems to be separate as far as information architecture goes. "Register" and "Sign In" are considered navigation items while "Request a Demo" is almost more of a marketing link that happens to be positioned near the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row nav-row">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Register</a>
    <a class="btn" href="#">Sign In</a>
</div>

<div class="row nav-row">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Request a demo</a>
</div>
```

That should work!

Answer (score 0):

Apply your own styles to below:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    <p class="navbar-btn">
      <a href="/" class="btn btn-default">Register</a>
      <a href="/" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</a>
    </p>
    <p class="navbar-btn">
      <a href="/" class="btn btn-default">Request a Demo</a>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```